# im getting a empty list after appending jobs to it

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

im trying to learn how to webscrape indeed.com for jobs i found a video on youtube and typed it exactly like he did but when i try to print the list it doesnt work it just gives me a empty list

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def extract(page):
    headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, likeGecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36'}
    url=f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Python%20Developer&l=Augusta%2C%20GA&start={page}&vjk=5ab1434abb63a27b'
    r=requests.get(url,headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    divs=soup.find_all('div',class_='jobsearch-SerpJobCard')
    for item in divs:
        title=item.find('a').text.strip()
        # print(title)
        company=item.find('span',class_='company').text.strip()
        # print(company)
        try:
            salary=item.find('span',class_='salaryText').text.strip()
            # print(salary)
        except:
            salary=''

        job={
            'title': title,
            'company': company,
            'salary': salary
        }
        joblist.append(job)
    return


joblist=[]
c=extract(20)
transform(c)
print(joblist)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how is my divs empty i dont understand

Answer (score 1):

In your `transform()` function you set your local variable `joblist` not global, you need to add `global joblist` at the beginning of function.

Otherwise fix your `return` statement, if you want to return instead, use `return joblist` and take using `joblist = transform(c)`

Comment: now its still giving me an empty list its something with the divs for loop but i dont understand how to fix it